# Puppet: Server hostname did not match server certificate

Tags: certificate, puppet, agent

I installed Puppet Enterprise on two virtual machines (one master and one node). When I try to run my agent manually with puppet agent -t i get the error

```
Server hostname '192.168....' did not match server certificate; expected one of host-192-168-.....localdomain.
```

If i run this by adding `--server host-192-168.....localdomain` it works, but this way i can do this manually and after its own `runInterval` it doesn't work so on my puppet console it says it is Unresponsive. I guess this is because on its own it gets the error i mentioned earlier so my master can't receive any reports from this node.

Can someone please help me with this? How can i make so my node's agent is contacting the master with the proper server certificate name?

puppet.conf from node:

```
[main]

vardir = ...
logdir = ...
rundir = ...
basemodulepath = ...
user = ...
group = ...
archive_files = ...

[agent]

report = ...
classfile = ...
localconfig = ...
graph = ...
pluginsync = ...
environment = ...
server = 192.168.10.39
certname = 192.168.10.40
noop = true
runinterval = 1800
```

If i put server = host-... (in main) nothing changes. I think I can't change the server from [agent] part, because there should be the master ip (i believe) ...

I tried what was on that link and now my puppet agent -t doesn't do anything anymore on my node. For better understandig, i'm posting my puppet.conf from master:

```
[main]

certname = host-192-168-10-39.localdomain
vardir = /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet
logdir = /var/log/pe-puppet
rundir = /var/run/pe-puppet
basemodulepath = /opt/alu/deploy/puppet/modules:/etc/puppetlabs/puppet....
environmentpath = /opt/alu/deploy/puppet/environments
server = 192.168.10.39
user = pe-puppet
group = pe-puppet
archive_files = true
archive_files_server = 192.168.10.39
module_groups = base+pe_only
dns_alt_names = puppet

[agent]

report = true
classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
graph = true
pluginsync = true
environment = production
noop = true
runinterval = 1800

[master]

node_terminus = classfier
ca_server = host-192-168-10-39.localdomain
reports = console,puppetdb
storeconfigs = true
storeconfigs_backend = puppetdb
certname = 192-168-10-39.localdomain
server = 192.168.10.39
always_cache_features = true
default_manifest = /opt/alu/deploy/puppet/manifests/default.pp
```

Error from puppet agent -t : http://i62.tinypic.com/34ijlmu.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of causes for this problem, Please list your puppet.conf.

But from top, it looks like some mismatch between the name in the certificate generated by the master and the host name of the server. Perhaps between when you generated the certificate and rebooted, the hostname had been changed, as hostname changes sometimes do not take affect until after a reboot.

puppetlabs Offical documentaion helps to resolve this issue, please follow this link: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/troubleshooting.html?_ga=1.110966791.343491524.1432986084#agents-are-failing-with-a-hostname-was-not-match-with-the-server-certificate-error-whats-wrong. It may be as simple as setting the certname value in /etc/puppet/conf and restarting the master.

Comment: I tried what you said and my puppet agent -t stopped working.... so i reversed everything. I edited my question with my both puppet.conf from master and node so you can have a better look. Please help :)

Comment: Hey @Robert as guided in the link, can please keep the certname  and hostname (I looked at your puppet.conf file) same 192-168-10-39.localdomain. I advise follow the steps again, i am sure you resolve it because your puppet.conf is exactly opposite to what mentioned in the puppetlabs documentation link.

Comment: @Robert , just a addition, It is good if you remove the  <confdir>/ssl public_keys from the agent and on server execute  "puppet cert clean <your server>  # against clients".  and start over to get this to work. Robert please feel free to add a note, i can understand these are pathetic problems.

Comment: I resolved this by changing the "server=" in the agent puppet.conf to host-192-168-10-39.localdomain. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of issuing `--server` on the command line, just add add `server=...` in the `[main]` section of the agent's `puppet.conf` file.

Comment: @Robert please don't share it in a comment. Add it to your question if need be.

Answer (score 0):

**Update the Puppet Client’s Configuration:** If the server can be reached via the name on its certificate (**e.g., puppet-master.local**), update the server setting in the **Puppet client’s puppet.conf** file to use this name.

I had it saved as puppet-master which is the hostname but instead changing it to puppet-master.local worked for me

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35698989)